# Optical Flow method returning unexpected values

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

This past two weeks I have been trying to create an Android App that tracks points in space as I move my Samsung Galaxy III's camera. In short, I use the OpenCV libraries to try to track said points using the two following methods:

```
public static void goodFeaturesToTrack(
                   Mat image,
                   MatOfPoint corners,
                   int maxCorners,
                   double qualityLevel,
                   double minDistance);
```

Were ***image*** corresponds to a 8-bit gray image, ***corners*** corresponds to the output with the best points to be used for tracking, ***maxCorners*** corresponds to the maximum number of points to be obtained, ***qualityLevel*** corresponds to a fraction such that all points to be obtained must be **>= BestQualityPointValue*qualityLevel** and ***minDistance*** corresponds to the minimum distance between points to be found. ([Link](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#goodFeaturesToTrack%28org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint,%20int,%20double,%20double%29))

```
public static void calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(
                    Mat prevImg,
                    Mat nextImg,
                    MatOfPoint2f prevPts,
                    MatOfPoint2f nextPts,
                    MatOfByte status,
                    MatOfFloat err);
```

Were ***prevImg*** corresponds to a 8-bit gray image at time **t**, ***nextImg*** corresponds to a 8-bit gray image at time **t+dt**, ***prevPts*** corresponds to the matrix containing the 2D(x,y) points to be tracked,  ***nextPts*** corresponds to the *OUTPUT* matrix containing the *NEW POSITION* of the points, ***status*** indicates which points have been tracked(**1**) and which not(**0**) AND ***err*** contains the error associated with those points whose displacement has been computed. ([Link](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/video/Video.html#calcOpticalFlowPyrLK%28org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint2f,%20org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint2f,%20org.opencv.core.MatOfByte,%20org.opencv.core.MatOfFloat%29))

So far I have been successful using the **goodFeaturesToTrack(...)** method, but I am still unable to calculate the *FLOW* of the points using **calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(...)** method.

**Here is the chunk of code that takes care of initializing the variables and tracking the points:**

```
  private static final double MIN_FEATURE_QUALITY = 0.05;
  private static final double MIN_FEATURE_DISTANCE = 4.0;
  
  private Mat               prevGray;
  private MatOfPoint2f      prev2D,next2D;
  private MatOfPoint        corners;
  private MatOfByte         status;
  private MatOfFloat        err;
  private Scalar            color;
  private Size              winSize;
  private int               maxCorners,maxLevel;
  
  ...
  
  public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {

  nextGray = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1); //unsigned char
  Rscale = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
  prevGray = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
  prev2D = new MatOfPoint2f(new Point());
  next2D = new MatOfPoint2f(new Point());                           
  status = new MatOfByte();                             
  err = new MatOfFloat();   
  corners = new MatOfPoint();
  maxLevel = 0;
  winSize = new Size(21,21);
  color = new Scalar(0, 255, 0);
  maxCorners = 1;
  }
  
  //THIS IS THE METHOD THAT TAKES CARE OF TRACKING THE POINTS
  public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
 
  nextGray = inputFrame.gray();
  Rscale = nextGray;
  
  if(!corners.empty()){
      Video.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(
              prevGray,
              nextGray,
              prev2D,
              next2D,
              status,
              err,
              winSize,
              maxLevel);
      System.out.println("status = " + status.toArray()[0]);
      System.out.println("err = " + err.toArray()[0]);
  }
  
  
  
  prevGray = nextGray;
  prev2D = next2D;
  for(int i=0;i<next2D.toArray().length;i++){
      Core.circle(Rscale, next2D.toArray()[i], 3, color,-1);
  }
  System.out.println("Prev2D = " + prev2D.toArray()[0].toString());
  System.out.println("Next2D = " + next2D.toArray()[0].toString());       
  return Rscale;
 
  }
```

**THE PROBLEM:**
As mentioned earlier, the parameter ***status*** tells the user if the flow has been computed or not for each point. Using ***System.out.println(...)***, I check each point status and **they are all 1**. Moreover, I also check the error and get that **error = 0.0** However, and this is what is killing me, the new computed points are always the same as the input points (**i.e. nextPts = prevPts**). This being said, **sometimes the points may change position by tiny amounts that are imperceptible**, but that rarely happens...

Comment: Set *maxLevel* to 3 or 4 instead of zero.

Comment: I already did that. Didn't work

Comment: Befor doing this calcOpticalFlowPyrLK you should do this next2D = new MatOfPoint2D(). Did it work?

Comment: PeterNL, I already initialized `next2D = new MatOfPoint2f(new Point());` in the `onCameraViewStarted(...)` method (which is called before the onCameraFrame method)

Comment: yes sure i see you do this. But I remember you have to clear the to filled array before. So before you call calcOpticalFlowPyrLK the next2D has to be empty. At the moment it isn't!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
prevGray = nextGray;
```

this *shallow* copy will lead to both Mat's point to the same pixel data. so, in the next iteration, when you say:

```
nextGray = inputFrame.gray();
```

prevGray will get updaded to the very same pixels, too ;)

what you want is a *deep* copy:

```
 prevGray = nextGray.clone();
 prev2D = next2D.clone();  // same story..
```

Comment: I already answered the question myself in an old post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23998775/android-app-tracking-points-video-calcopticalflow-method-not-working-prope). But thanks.